# self scrolling page as elements apear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code jQuery

```
$(".col-md-12").hide();
$(".button-div").hide();
$(".featurette-divider").hide();
$(".footer").hide();
$(".first").fadeIn(1000);
$(".second").delay(900).fadeIn(1000);
$(".third").delay(1800).fadeIn(1000);
$(".fourth").delay(2700).fadeIn(1000);
$(".button-div").delay(3600).fadeIn(1000);
$(".featurette-divider").delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
$(".footer").delay(5000).fadeIn(1000);
```

I want to make the page scroll by itself to the bottom as the elements appear on it.

**EDIT 1**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 first">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 second">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 third">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 fourth">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="centered button-div">
      <!-- Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>© 2015 · <a href="#">About</a> · <a href="#">Contact</a></p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

My HTML layout (Bootrstrap based). I've pasted the wrapper where all the content goes (.container)

Comment: Have you taken a look at scrollTop function? Do you have a wrapping div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JQuery's scrolltop function, you can scroll your page to a given height in pixels:

```
$(document).scrollTop(heightInPixels);
```

This would scroll your whole document to the end:

```
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
$(document).scrollTop(documentHeight);
```

If you want this to happen as each element appears, you will have to call this everytime after the effect, or put a callback when the effects are over:

```
function scrollDocument(){
  var documentHeight = $(document).height();
  $(document).scrollTop(documentHeight);
}

// Element "appearings"
$(".first").fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument );
....
$( ".footer" ).delay(5000).fadeIn(1000, scrollDocument );
```

I hope this helps. To help more, I should have more info about your layout...

EDIT

```js
$(".col-md-12").hide();
$(".button-div").hide();
$(".featurette-divider").hide();
$(".footer").hide();


function scrollDocument(){
  var contentHeight = $(document).height();
  $(document).scrollTop(contentHeight);
}

// Element "appearings"

$(".first").fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".second").delay(900).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".third").delay(1800).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".fourth").delay(2700).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".button-div").delay(3600).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".featurette-divider").delay(4000).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
$(".footer").delay(5000).fadeIn(1000,  scrollDocument);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 first">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description1</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 second">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description2</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 third">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description3</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 fourth">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>hero name</h3>
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p></p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-xs-1">
                <col class="col-xs-7">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Abilities</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description4</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.active</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.success</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a successful or positive action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.info</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a neutral informative change or action</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.warning</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a warning that might need attention</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <code>.danger</code>
                  </th>
                  <td>Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div><!-- end col-lg-6 -->

    <div class="centered button-div">
      <!-- Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>© 2015 · <a href="#">About</a> · <a href="#">Contact</a></p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Just chage the $(document) selector by your $('div.container') on the code above and that should work.

Comment: @АтанасЧомполов try the solution above on your container div.

Comment: @АтанасЧомполов I added a working snippet. Take a look.